# How to detect conflicting strings from a list of JSON given a Complex JSON?

Tags: java, mysql, json, jooq

Given a combination of multiple **conditions** with operators in between, for ex.

```
section = "ABC" AND type = "A" AND status = "RESPONDED" AND scores NOT_NULL AND scores.productA NOT_NULL AND scores.productA > 10 AND scores.productA < 30
```

That results in multiple **actions**, for ex.

```
priority = 3 AND hours = 24 AND isQualified = true
```

Goal is to find JSON strings that would conflict with this string. Conflict would be when
same **conditions** (same or different order) result in different **actions** or result in **actions** with different values
Have a mysql table that stores these json strings in a column and need to query against that column

Have tried MySQL JSON functions like JSON_CONTAINS but it does not work if order of nested json objects is different.
Also tried string comparison using LIKE for individual conditions which worked but for a match to happen we
need to consider the grouping of conditions and the operators joining them.

Any suggestions would be great. Ideally being able to do it at SQL level would be great but a combination of SQL to narrow down and then do a second pass on narrowed values might work too.

JSON string to represent **conditions** and **actions** can be specified like

```
{
    "actions": [{
        "actionItem": {
            "SetValueAction": {
                "value": {
                    "long": 24
                },
                "dataField": {
                    "field": "hours",
                    "object": {
                        "className": "Message",
                        "objectName": "message"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "actionItem": {
            "SetValueAction": {
                "value": {
                    "boolean": true
                },
                "dataField": {
                    "field": "isQualified",
                    "object": {
                        "className": "Message",
                        "objectName": "message"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "actionItem": {
            "SetValueAction": {
                "value": {
                    "long": 3
                },
                "dataField": {
                    "field": "priority",
                    "object": {
                        "className": "Message",
                        "objectName": "message"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    "condition": {
        "ConditionGroup": {
            "logicalOperator": "AND",
            "conditionGroupItems": [{
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "value": {
                                "string": "ABC"
                            },
                            "operator": "EQ",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "section",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "value": {
                                "string": "A"
                            },
                            "operator": "EQ",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "type",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "value": {
                                "string": "RESPONDED"
                            },
                            "operator": "EQ",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "status",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "operator": "NOT_NULL",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "scores",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "operator": "NOT_NULL",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "scores.productA",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "value": {
                                "double": 10
                            },
                            "operator": "GT",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "scores.productA",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "Condition": {
                    "conditionItem": {
                        "FieldConstraint": {
                            "value": {
                                "double": 30
                            },
                            "operator": "LE",
                            "dataField": {
                                "field": "scores.productA",
                                "object": {
                                    "className": "Message",
                                    "objectName": "message"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sophisticated frameworks to cater your requirement in SQL .
With Java - it's straightforward.

However - u can build a logic in mysql with below inputs

1.) Use JSON_SEARCH with text condition 1.) "condition" 2.) "actionnItem" and give 'all' search to return all the matching string path
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

2.) You will have two outputs sets for condition and actionItem

3.) Now have two seperate while loops for each and parse through from the paths identified in step 1/2, and do a json_search again on operator , datafield and other texts based on your JSON format.

Detailed JSON functions are available here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: Srikanth, thank you for the response. Could you please elaborate on how is doing the JAVA way straightforward? All the JSONs in the list will have conditions and actionItems, the two separate loops will be over all the JSONs if I understand your point correctly. I have looked at JSON_SEARCH and other functions but having just the value of say operator, datafield.field might not work, the path to that value (levels of nesting) also need to match to narrow the search space.

Comment: to clarify, are steps 1-3 in SQL or its a combination with Java? Could you elaborate on step 3 using JSON_SEARCH?

Comment: Hi, it's via sql function, you can built this logic - since you preferred SQL - I have added SQL steps